# Injective modules equivalence

Tags: modules, injective-module

Let $Q$ a left $R$-module, we have that are equivalent:

a. If $X$ and $Y$ are left $R$-modules and $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is an injective module homomorphism and $g : X \rightarrow Q$ is an arbitrary module homomorphism, then there exists a module homomorphism $h : Y \rightarrow Q$ such that $hf = g$

b. Given $0\rightarrow X \xrightarrow{f} Y \xrightarrow{g} Z \rightarrow 0$ an exact short sequence, then $$0\rightarrow Hom_R(Z,Q) \xrightarrow{g^*} Hom_R(y,Q) \xrightarrow{f^*} Hom_R(X,Q) \rightarrow 0$$ is exact.

I've proven that $b \Rightarrow a$ but on the other direction I don't know how to prove that $Ker f^* \subseteq Im g^*.$ I don't know how to approach this.

edit: I made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

To prove that $Ker f^*\subset Im g^*$ you don't need condition a. Let $h:Y\to Q$ be in the kernel of $f^*$, that is $h\circ f=0$. Then by the universal property of the cokernel of $f$, there is a unique $k:Z\to Q$ such that $k\circ g=h$, i.e. $h$ is in the image of $g^*$.

More generally, the last sequence you wrote is always exact at the first two Hom spaces. Condition a is only telling you that $f^*$ is surjective.

Comment: Oh sorry! I was thinking about injective modules and I totally didn't realize I wrote that. Thank you!!! Can I do this without the cokernel universal property? Something less elaborated since I haven't studied that.

Comment: You can define $k:Z\to Q$ as $k(z):=h(y)$, where $y\in g^{-1}(z)$. Check it is independent of the choice of $y$ and that it has the required property. In fact, this is the proof of the universal property of the cokernel.